# Is it possible a closed expression for $1^k + 2^k + ... + n^k$? If so, am I on the way?

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I was asked to calculate the sequence $1^k + 2^k + ... + n^k$ and if it is possible to find a closed expression for it for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
I could find that I can rewrite $\sum_{i=1}^ni^k$ into $1^k + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (1+i)^k$. Also it seemed to me that I could without prejudice use the superior summation limit as $n$, so that I would have a sum of binomial expressions (using $(n-1)$ the last term would be $n^k$ and for that I was unsure if I could use the binomial theorem within the sum).
Rewriting $1^k + \sum_{i=1}^{n} (1+i)^k$ again (using the mentioned theorem) I got:
$1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j}i^j$, but now I'm stuck. Any tips? Am I on a reasonable course?

Comment: take a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula

Comment: And search the site. This has been asked so many times on our site that I have lost count.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878810/formula-for-1k2k3k-nk-for-n-k-in-mathbbn

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* You could find in *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801457/closed-form-for-1k-nk-generalized-harmonic-number/1802085#1802085)* formulas for the sum of $k$-th powers of the first $n$ natural numbers.

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=1}^nj^k&=[z^n]\frac{1}{1-z}(zD_z)^k\frac{1}{1-z}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^k{k\brace j}\frac{(n+1)^{\underline{j+1}}}{j+1}
> \end{align*}

with $D_z:=\frac{d}{dz}$ the *[differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator)* and ${k\brace j}$ *[Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)*.