# Repeated Differences of the series 1^n 2^n 3^n 4^n…

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I kind of stumbled across this pattern recently and cant make any sense of it. Attached is my work explaining what I did. If there is already an answer to this please post the link. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You've got a couple of errors on $n=3$, namely, $34-19\neq18$ and $61-34\neq24$.

Comment: Right, 34 should be 37, i copied my messy work quickly to a clean page.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878810/formula-for-1k2k3k-nk-for-n-k-in-mathbbn/1878949#187894 may be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more natural to start the sequence at $0$: for example,

$$0 \quad 1 \quad 4 \quad 9$$ $$1 \quad 3 \quad 5$$ $$2 \quad 2$$ $$0$$

from which you can read off the leftmost side that the top (the sequence $n^2$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$) is actually $$\color{red}{0} \cdot \binom{n}{0} + \color{red}{1} \cdot \binom{n}{1} + \color{red}{2} \cdot \binom{n}{2} = n + 2 \cdot \frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$

This idea goes by the name Binomial transform.

The fact that you will end up with the last coefficient $k!$ when studying the sequence $1^k,2^k,3^k$ is because the coefficient of $n^k$ in $\binom{n}{k}$ itself is exactly $1/k!$; and you need the result to be $1 \cdot n^k.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  If you form a row
$$p(1)\quad p(2)\quad p(3)\quad\cdots$$
from *any* polynomial
$$p(x)=ax^n+\cdots\ ,$$
then the next row will be
$$q(1)\quad q(2)\quad q(3)\quad\cdots$$
where
$$q(x)=nax^{n-1}+\cdots\ .$$