# Given a sequence find nth term

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Suppose a sequence is given -: 3, 8, 20, 43, 83, 148 ...

We can find the differences between consecutive terms and do that over and over again until we have same differences (as Pascal's triangle)

```
3   8   20  43  83  148
 \ / \ / \ / \ / \ /
  5  12   23  40  65
   \ / \ / \ / \ /
    7   11  17  25
     \ / \ / \ /
      4   6   8
       \ / \ /
        2   2
```

How to find 'n-th term' and 'sum of first n term' of these kind of sequences?

Comment: If you have to take differences $d$ times to get a constant then you can fit a $d$ degree polynomial and you have enough information to set up $d+1$ simultaneous equations to find the coefficients.  For the cumulative sum, obviously you need to take differences $d+1$ times to get the same constant and you can find the corresponding $d+1$ degree polynomial.  This is an exercise in [discrete calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)

Comment: Have a look at this: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.353.27&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Check out part $(1)$ of my answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878810/formula-for-1k2k3k-nk-for-n-k-in-mathbbn/1878949#1878949 as to why, if we assume all other first terms of the differences are $0$, and let $a_0$ represent the first term we have $a_n=3{n \choose 0}+5{n \choose 1}+7{n \choose 2}+4{n \choose 3}+2{n \choose 4}$. Notice the connection with the first terms of the sequences above.

Comment: For the sum, use the hockey stick identity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we rotate the triangle $120^\circ$ (assuming the triangle is equilateral) clockwise, we have the following (original series shown in red; ignore items in blue and green for now):

> $$\begin{array}
> &&&&&&&&\\
> &\color{blue}{a_6}&&a_5 &&a_4 &&a_3 &&a_2&&a_1&&a_0\\
> &\color{blue}\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow &&\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
> &\color{blue} 0&&0 &&2 && 4 &&7 &&5 &&\color{red}3\\
> &&\color{blue}0 &&2  &&6  &&11 &&12  &&\color{red}8 &\color{red}\uparrow\\
> &&& \color{blue}2&&8  &&17 &&23  &&\color{red}{20}&\color{red}\uparrow&\color{red}{b_0}\\
> &&&&\color{blue}{10}&&25  &&40 &&\color{red}{43}&\;\color{red}\uparrow&\color{red}{b_1}\\
> &&&&&\color{blue}{35}&&65 &&\color{red}{83}&\;\color{red}\uparrow&\;\color{red}{b_2}\\
> &&&&&&\color{blue}{100}&&\color{red}{148}&\;\color{red}\uparrow&\;\color{red}{b_3}\\
> &&&&&&&\color{green}{248}&\;\color{red}\uparrow&\;\color{red}{b_4}\\
> &&&&&&&\color{green}{\;\;\uparrow}&\;\color{red}{b_5}\\
> &&&&&&&\color{green}{\;\;b_6}
> \end{array}$$

In this triangle, any number is the sum of the two numbers above it and immediately to the left and right, similar to Pascal's triangle. Hence we have

$$
\begin{align}
b_0&=\binom 00a_0\\
b_1&=\binom 10 a_1+\binom 11 a_0\\
b_2&=\binom 20a_0+\binom 21a_1+\binom 22a_2\\
&\vdots \\
b_n&=\sum_{r=0}^n \binom nr a_r
\end{align}$$

Further, if the bottom row in the number triangle in the original question has elements of $2$ all the way, this means $a_r=0$ for $r\ge5$. We can then compute $b_n$ with only $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4$, the values of which we already have.

Hence, the general formula for $b_n$ becomes
$$\color{red}{b_n=\sum_{r=0}^{\min(4,n)} \binom nr a_r}\\
\color{red}{(a_r=3,5,7,4,2 \text{ for } r=0,1,2,3,4)}$$

This is also  general formula for $n$-th term of the original series (the first term indexed as $n=0$).

**Sum of first $n$ terms**

The sum of the first $n$ terms is given by

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}b_j
&=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\sum_{r=0}^{\min (4,j)}\binom jr a_r\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{\min(4,n-1)}  \sum_{j=r}^{n-1}\binom jr a_r\\
&=\color{red}{\sum_{r=0}^{\min(4,n-1)}  \binom n{r+1} a_r}\\
\end{align}$$

(see the solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2101813/168053) for an illustration)

---

**Check**

As a quick check, we compute $b_6$ by hand (shown in blue and green in the diagram) and arrive at $248$.

Using the formula, we have
$$b_6=\binom 61 \cdot 3 +\binom 62\cdot 5+\binom 63\cdot 7+\binom 64\cdot 4+\binom 65\cdot 2=248$$
as well.

---

**Additional Note**

It is interesting to note that we can compute $a_n$ directly from $b_r (r=0,1,\cdots n)$, using
$$a_n=\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^{n+r}\binom nr b_r$$

For instance, $a_3=-1(3)+3(8)-3(20)+1(43)=4$.

This is because the inverse of a Pascal matrix (a left-aligned Pascal's triangle) is *also* a Pascal matrix, but with elements of alternating sign!
(*Discovered this in the course of solving this problem!*)

Comment: Wow, wtf kind of trickery is this?!  I give you an **$\color{red}{\large\mathbf{A}\text{+}}$**

Comment: @SimpleArt - Thanks! Very kind of you :)

Comment: The result in your **Additional Note** is also a consequence of the [Möbius inversion formula](http://www.sfu.ca/~mdevos/notes/comb_struct/mobius.pdf) [PDF] on the poset of subsets of $[n]$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the bottom row is given by

$$a_n=2$$

So that the row above it is given by

$$b_n=2(n+1)$$

And the row above

$$c_n=5+n(n+1)$$

And

$$d_n=5n+\frac{n(n^2-1)}3$$

So finally, we have

$$e_n=3+\frac{5n(n-1)}2+\frac{n(n^2-1)(n-2)}{12}$$

And the sum of the first $n$ terms would be given by the row above that,

$$f_n=3n+\frac{5n(n-1)(n-2)}6+\frac{n(n^2-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{60}$$

---

As to how I found those, I used the fact that

$$x_k(n+1)-x_k(n)=x_{k-1}(n)$$

where

$$x_k(n)=\frac{(n+1)(n+0)(n-1)\dots(n+1-k)}{k!}$$

which is basically how your triangle was constructed.

---

Also, the sum of each line is equal to the above line plus a constant.